# How does number at JavaScript works

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have this code in javascript

```
let a = 1;
let b = 0.8;
let c = a-b
```

I expect the value of c to be equal to 0.2, but the value I get is 0.19999999999999996 
does any one have an explanation

Comment: `I expect the value of c to equal 2` how is that possible?

Comment: how can `1-0.8` equal `2`?

Comment: @M.Amer i think you mean `I expect the value of c to equal 0.2`

Comment: yes. I mean 0.2